# How to view a PE EXE/DLL file version information?

Tags: wine

In Windows there is a version information page in an executable/library file properties window. How to view that info in Ubuntu?

Comment: Do you mean how to view such information from Linux binaries/libraries or windows EXE/DLL using a Linux utility ?

Comment: As I've clearly specified in the question title, I mean PE (Windows) EXE and DLL files (to view using a Linux utility of course).

Answer (score 51):

I'm working in a tool called [**pev**](http://pev.sf.net) to retrieve information about PE files on the command line.

It is installable with

```
sudo apt-get install pev
```

The file version can be fetched with

```
peres -v program.exe | awk '{print $3}'
```

Comment: @Ivan you might consider accepting this answer instead.

Comment: These instructions are [outdated](http://pev.sourceforge.net/doc/manual/en_us/ch01.html). You might wish to consider updating them.

Comment: The pev package in current debian distros doesn't contain a binary

Comment: In Ubuntu the command should be `peres -v program.exe | awk '{print $3}'` after `sudo apt install pev`

Comment: `pev -p` works fine in Ubuntu 16.04. Just used to check Windows version remotely: `pev -p /mnt/windows_host/Windows/explorer.exe`

Answer (score 18):

From the `gnome-exe-thumbnailer` script, suggested by Scott Ritchie:

```
wrestool --extract --raw --type=version inputfile.exe
```

extracts the version information, printing some binary data mixed with UTF-16 text. The script converts it to readable text by piping it through:

```
tr '\0, ' '\t.\0' \
| sed 's/\t\t/_/g' \
| tr -c -d '[:print:]' \
| sed -r -n 's/.*Version[^0-9]*([0-9]+\.[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?).*/\1/p'
```

The overall command is then `wrestool --extract --raw --type=version inputfile.exe | tr '\0, ' '\t.\0' | sed 's/\t\t/_/g' | tr -c -d '[:print:]' | sed -r -n 's/.*Version[^0-9]*([0-9]+\.[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?).*/\1/p'`.

Comment: +1 `wrestool` is provided by the `icoutil` package which is available as a standard Debian package since way back.

Comment: you may make it simpler by just pipe it through `| hexdump -C`

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04 it is inside the ```icoutils``` package.

Answer (score 14):

As an alternative to using **tr** and **sed** to parse the output from @mechanical-snail 's solution, here is a GNU **strings** and GNU **grep** version:

```
$ wrestool --extract --raw --type=version putty.exe | strings -el | grep Version -A 1

FileVersion
Release 0.65
ProductVersion
Release 0.65
```

UPDATE:

Another alternative is a recent version of **[exiftool](https://exiftool.org/)** by Phil Harvey (it is based on perl, easy to install with `sudo apt-get install libimage-exiftool-perl`, also available for Mac and Windows). It has lots of formatting options.

```
# Example with exiftool 10.47
$ exiftool -FileVersion -ProductVersion putty.exe

File Version                    : Release 0.67
Product Version                 : Release 0.67
```

Comment: What package in Ubuntu/Debian has exiftool? Looks like `libimage-exiftool-perl`?

Comment: I just download the source code and build it locally. 

Download the tar.gz file from the website (The "Download Version xx.yy" link at the top of http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/), extract the files and see the INSTALLATION section of the README file for how to build it using perl and then installing it to /usr/local/bin

Comment: Would never expect `exiftool` to handle executables...

Comment: `exiftool` is very powerful!

Answer (score 6):

If you install the `gnome-exe-thumbnailer` package, you can simply look at the version number in `nautilus`, `caja` ,`nemo` and `thunar`.

The code to do this manually is available in `/usr/bin/gnome-exe-thumbnailer.sh`

Comment: @Scott.. Thanks. it works.. the relevant code is very simple to use in another script... I assume that what you mean by *"you can simply look at the version number in nautilus"*, is that that the version number appears grafted into the .exe's icon in Nautilus.. an interesting idea.. Personally, I rarely use the icon-view, but the code snippet is great for me..

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here's something you can do if you can't install new applications, but you do have p7zip and Vim:

1. Extract the metadata with `7z x whatever.exe .rsrc/VERSION/1`
2. Open the resulting `.rsrc/VERSION/1` file in Vim
3. Type `:e ++enc=utf16le` at the Vim command line to request that the file's contents be reinterpreted as little-endian UTF-16.

Answer (score 0):

The method mentioned in @ssokolow's answer does not work exactly for me.

However, the `7z`'s (version 16.02 or above) "list" option will list that information already.

So, I defined the following Bash function:

```bsh
function lspe
{
  7z l "$1" | sed -n -e '/^Comment =/,/^$/ p' | sed 's/^Comment = //'
}
```

You can put this function in your `.bash_aliases` file and use like this:

```
lspe executable.exe
```

Answer (score -1):

I just found out myself how to create a nice python dict with the information (I was looking around myself and wound up here for some reason) and would like to present my method here: 
[Github Gists - spookyahell/exe2version_info.py](https://gist.github.com/spookyahell/b317bdf0712aac5fd37dd79f70bfbe69)

```python
'''Licensed under the MIT License :)'''

import pefile
import pprint
pe =  pefile.PE('example.exe')


string_version_info = {}

for fileinfo in pe.FileInfo[0]:
    if fileinfo.Key.decode() == 'StringFileInfo':
        for st in fileinfo.StringTable:
            for entry in st.entries.items():
                string_version_info[entry[0].decode()] = entry[1].decode()

pprint.pprint(string_version_info)
```

I am licensing it under the MIT License... may anybody who feels the need to create useful scripts or other things with it...

And see [Github Gists - spookyahell/peinfo.py](https://gist.github.com/spookyahell/ae38a2a349965c11c27627162d783212#file-peinfo-py) for an example implementation of this method in another script...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.